# find array in template using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Way to find array in result variable

$scope.result = [1,2,6,5,4,3];

I have to check manually like below

```
<li ng-show="result == 1 || result == '1,2' || result == '2,1'">Something</li>
```

is there any shortcut idea that can check if there is any value into array

Way to find array in result variable

Comment: Do this on controller side, it will make view more readable.

Answer (score 3):

try something like this

```
<li ng-if="result.length > 0">Something</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
 <li ng-show="result.length!=0">Something</li>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/W8J4xdjNu7RdV4rQOtzV?p=preview

Comment: why did u use curly brackets . result is a scope variable. so no need to use the curly brackets

Comment: thanks for the insight, althought the result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to put < or > in there

```
<li ng-show="result.length">Something</li>
```

Just say `ng-show="result.length"` will work.

Answer (score 2):

If a filter is used in `ng-repeat`, the same filter must be applied to `ng-show`. If not, the ng-show will always refer to the full array :

```
<div ng-show="!(tags| filter:some ng-modal name defined).length">No Tag Found</div>
```

It's better to use `ng-hide`

```
<div ng-hide="tags.length">No Tag Found</div>
```

Use the function `indexOf` in array to find whether a element is part of the array. It will return the position of the element if found or will return -1.

```
ng-show = "tags.indexOf(CSS)!=-1"
```

Below is a simple fiddle example

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.tags = ['HTML', 'CSS', 'Jquery', 'Bootstrap', 'AngularJS'];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <input class="txt" type="text" ng-model="nameText" />
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="myKeys in tags| filter:nameText">{{myKeys}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-show="!(tags| filter:nameText).length">No Tag Found</div>
  </div>
</div>
```